# How do I use preg_replace to return part of a string?

Tags: php

I am trying to return mime types from an array. I have these strings in an array:

```
application/pdf
image/jpg
image/jpeg
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
pdf
jpg
jpeg
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but may I ask why?

Comment: I want to show the allowable filetypes to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use preg replace. For each string in the array...

```
$split = explode('/', $mime);
$type = $split[1];
```

Comment: Thanks Tesserex. It does work but Pekka has a good point and I may have to scrap this idea and make a different array.

Comment: Give this the credit because it actually answers the question

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show the allowable filetypes to the user

This may work fine in your specific case - I can't judge that -  but in general, it *would* be cleaner to have a separate array/column/whatever for the file extensions, e.g.

```
array(
    "application/pdf" => "pdf",
    "image/jpg" => "jpg",
    "image/jpeg" => "jpeg"
);
```

Consider `application/msword` (.doc) or `video/msvideo` (.avi) where MIME type and file extension have nothing to do with each other. Your desired method of using the last part of the MIME type would break there.

Comment: Hmmm... You know what? You make a very good point and I never considered that. Can you show me an example of hw you think this should go together?

Comment: @Nick how to do this will totally depend on your code. You'd have to show your code to get specific answers. Maybe worth another question

Comment: Um.. I actually don't see any errors involving double quotes. Both the key/value are strings so they go in quotes, no?

Comment: @Nick he was referring to a typo I made in the array example. I have since corrected it

Comment: @Pekka: Actually, I am only allowing pdf in one upload form and jpg, gif, png and jpeg so I think I should be ok with Tesserex's code. If I need other mimes, I can always make another array as you suggested.